# Can I configure a roaming user profile on a Windows Xp Pro SP3 system?

Tags: c++, windows, user-accounts, roaming-profile

For testing purposes I need to see how my code behaves when a Windows user account is set up as "roaming". Can I somehow configure my Windows XP SP3 Professional to do that (if not, what about Vista or Windows 7)?

Answer (score 0):

Certainly you can use roaming profiles with Windows XP SP3 professional.  However, the machine must be a member of a domain.  You'll also need a file server (in the same domain) to locate the roaming profile on.

You can configure the roaming profile location for your test account(s) using the Profile tab in Active Directory Users and Computers.